# Webpack dev server: issue mapping paths local to remote. Output/bundle files load in IDE/Chrome

Tags: debugging, webpack, phpstorm, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to line up my dev server output with a local project for debugging. PhpStorm support couldn't find out what the issue was as we worked on it though.

The issue with the current config is that it seems to pull up the output / bundle file in the IDE, instead of keeping to the source code files.

I'm mapping "remote" urls to what I see in Chrome under sources > webpack > .

[image: mappings]

The result (see top left pane):

[image: output variables]

And before the above, the bundle file is the first stop in the debugger before I click resume (it opens on its own in the editor):

[image: bundle file]

On the browser side, Chrome pauses script execution, but also jumps to the sources tab into a hard to read file, probably something compiled by webpack.

Here is my webpack config. Does anyone see what settings I have misconfigured? This is a React.js project (custom webpack config, create-react-app not used)

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenvWebpack = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    adminArea :
      ['./adminSettingsArea/src/index.jsx']
  },
  output : {
    filename : 'shared/[name].bundle.js',
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
    publicPath : "/",
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer : {
    contentBase : './adminSettingsArea/src',
    hot : true,
    historyApiFallback : true
  },
  plugins : [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new dotenvWebpack()
  ],
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude : [/node_modules/, /vendor/],
        use : {
          loader : "babel-loader",
          options : {
            presets : [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          },
        }
      }, {
        test : /\.css$/i,
        use : ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: try removing mappings - does it work?

Comment: @lena no unfortunately, with all mappings removed the script loads completely in bwoser, totally ignoring all mappings in the IDE

Comment: as I wrote, it works fine for me using your project...